# Python 3 for loop not breaking

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I am having an issue with the following while True block of code. When I run it, it creates the folders just fine, however it triggers the "file name wrong or does not exist." message and the program comes back asking the "Name of the file to be used for folder creation". It seems to restart the block of code over and over even though it created the files just fine but never breaks out of the loop?? I am new to programming and trying to get better at coding so any help is greatly appreciated. I apologize in advanced if there is already a post on this out there, but I tried searching before posting with no luck. Thanks

```
while True:
    try:
        file = input("Name of file to be used for folder creation. ")
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            print("Successful")
            with open(file, "r") as f: # This line down to the os.mkdir line, opens a file that user selects and makes folders based on the list of words inside, -
                for line in f:         # and strips off the white spaces before and after the lines.
                    os.mkdir(line.strip())
                break   # This block of code from "with open" line is NOT working correctly as it will create the folders, but will not break out of the loop and keeps asking for the name of the file to use.
        else:
            raise Exception
    except Exception as e:
        print("File name wrong, or file does not exist. ")
        time.sleep(3)
        cls()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in the usage of try/except or while/break.
Take a look at the Exception variable 'e'.
Is it really the exception that you throw on line 11?

You can add a line like this before line 13:

```
print(e.__str__())
```

, and find out what's wrong.

(In my case, a folder to be created already exists)

Therefore, perhaps you could define your own exception class and catch one. For example:

```
class WTFException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)
while True:
    try:
        file = input("Name of file to be used for folder creation. ")
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            print("Successful")
            with open(file, "r") as f: # This line down to the os.mkdir line, opens a file that user selects and makes folders based on the list of words inside, -
                for line in f:         # and strips off the white spaces before and after the lines.
                    os.mkdir(line.strip())
                break   # This block of code from "with open" line is NOT working correctly as it will create the folders, but will not break out of the loop and keeps asking for the name of the file to use.
        else:
            raise WTFException
    except WTFException as e:
        print("File name wrong, or file does not exist. ")
        time.sleep(3)
        cls()
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Oops') # Do something else here if you want
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it is not giving me any info it just suddenly closes after executing. However I added a line to print the exception and now it says "[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''   ". I am having a hard time understanding why this is as it creates the folders perfectly fine every time, it just doest break out it keeps repeating the beginning? And if it cant find the path specified how is it able to create the folders? Thanks

Comment: I suppose that the [WinError 3] took place on the **os.mkdir(line.strip())** line. Did you try modifying the file that you use for folder creation? Perhaps there is a blank line in it, according to your error message.

Comment: Debugging is important. Maybe print every variable before any relavant error could possibly occur. Also, you can use the debugger function of your IDE(like PyCharm or VS Code). Add a breakpoint before the line you'd like to check, and let the debugger stop at breakpoints, where you could check every breakpoint you want.

Comment: Now that you mention that, the text file I use has 4 lines of text at the top and couple blank lines then more text underneath. Would those blank lines be causing that error? Thanks

Comment: Okay I just tested this and it does appear that if there is any blank lines it throws this error message. Tested it with the same file but removed all the blank lines, and it worked flawlessly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is creating some of the folders you mentioned in your initial file, but there might be some error while creating some files at the ending because of which break is not being executed(exception in line **os.mkdir(line.strip())**). You are catching the exception but the loop doesn't break. As Harper mentioned always print the exception in the except block.

Comment: I tried harper longs suggestion but, hes not responding and it is not giving me any info it just suddenly closes after executing. However I added a line to print the exception and now it says "[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '' ". I am having a hard time understanding why this is as it creates the folders perfectly fine every time, it just doesnt break out, it keeps repeating the beginning? And if it cant find the path specified how is it able to create the folders? Any idea as to what may be going on and how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Did you make sure there are no trailing lines at the end of the file?

Comment: Yes I just recently did. That seemed to fix the issue. Thanks